# Moment JS Date to C# Date

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, momentjs

I have a WS made on C# and I need to send this type of format (/Date(1529536171)/) in the POST.

```
"object": { 
    "data": "data",
    "dateStart": "/Date(1529536171)/",          
}
```

How can I convert the date that Moment JS give me to that (strange) kind of format??

I tried sent a string with that format but it doesn't work.

Comment: What "1529536171" numbers represent?

Comment: _I need to send this type of format_ - does this mean, that on server side deserialiser will understand this format and will convert it to C# date automatically?

Comment: Exactly, the WS of C# was made to receive a Date Object on this (very strange) format. 1529536171 represents I guess the date on Unix format. But everytime y send the POST request, returns me a false indicate that the format of the date is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to a [unix timestamp](http://www.convert-unix-time.com/).  Moment.js gives you an object that you can format however you'd like.  To format it into a timestamp, try this :

```
moment.unix(yourMomentObject)
```

This will give you a timestamp.

If you want to format the object to human readable format, simply :

```
moment.unix(yourMomentObject).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Moment.js' documentation, you can use [`moment.unix(Number)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) to create a `moment` from a Unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch)

```
> let myMomentDate = moment.unix(1529543673)
> myMomentDate
moment("2018-06-20T20:14:33.000")
```

You can also call [`moment().unix()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) to get back a Unix timestamp.

```
> myMomentDate.unix() == 1529543673
true
```

So you can do the following to get to your desired format:

```
> '/Date(' + myMomentDate.unix() +')/'
'/Date(1529543673)/'
```

Comment: Believe me, I already tried to send a string just like you do, but it doesn't work.